# using nextSibling from BeautifulSoup outputs nothing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup on the following:

```
<h4>Hello<br /></h4>
<p><img src="http://url.goes.here" alt="hiya" class="img" />May 28, 1996</p>
```

For this example, let's say I have the `<h4>` tag saved in the variable `tag`. When I type `print tag.text` the output is `Hello`, as expected.

However, when I use `print tag.nextSibling` the output is nothing. When I type `print tag.nextSibling.nextSibling`, the output is `<p><img src="http://url.goes.here" alt="hiya" class="img" />May 28, 1996</p>`. What is going on? Why do I have to double up on the use of `.nextSibling` to get to the `<p>` tag in my example? This is consistently an error.

Comment: I don't get an error. What's the OS and Python version?

Comment: sorry there's not a real error, like printed on the terminal. To me, it makes sense that tag.nextSibling should grab the entire <p> tag and its contents, but it doesn't. It's grabbing something blank. tag.nextSibling.nextSibling is grabbing the <p> tag. It seems like one too many nextSibling's...

Comment: sorry, I mean semantic error. I call `print tag.nextSibling` and get the output that you expected but did not get.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, .nextSibling **will** grab white text. So in the actual page I'm working with, there is white text between the `<h4>` and `<p>` tags, which is why I have to double.

**Evidence**

Writing:

```
print tag.__class__
print tag.nextSibling.__class__
print tag.nextSibling.nextSibling.__class__
```

Yields:

```
<class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'>
<class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
```

Comment: This is not the case on Windows, BTW. I'm currently testing this on my Mac to see if it's a bug in BeautifulSoup for Mac.

Comment: I don't think this has to be a bug, as whitespace would be of the NavigableString type. I'll run a test and post the results in a few minutes.

Comment: it's my fault, I didn't put a new line when I first tested on Windows. I get the same behavior on Windows, Mac, and Linux

Comment: instead of `next_sibling` use `find_next_sibling()`. which will return the next html tag ignoring whitespace and other non html syntax elements. same for `previous_sibling` and `find_previous_sibling()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is what written in the official documentation:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-down

In real documents, the .next_sibling or .previous_sibling of a tag will usually be a string containing whitespace. Going back to the “three sisters” document:

```
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a>
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>
```

You might think that the .next_sibling of the first  tag would be the second  tag. But actually, it’s a string: the comma and newline that separate the first  tag from the second:

```
link = soup.a
link
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>

link.next_sibling
# u',\n'
```

The second  tag is actually the .next_sibling of the comma:

```
link.next_sibling.next_sibling
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>
```

Comment: Upvoted because this answer was very helpful in understanding why BS4 acts this way, and the examples were good ones. But it was a bit confusing to read at first, because the word "**comma**" was mistakenly used everywhere instead of "**comment**".